# Check value of first row of column in listView?

Tags: c#, listview

I have this if statement where I check if a column contains a certain item. I remember being told that the way I have it that it'll only check for the last item in that certain column.

Column 5 contains numbers.

How do I make it so the if statement applies to the first item in column 5?

```
 foreach (ListViewItem i in listView1.Items)
 {
     if (Convert.ToInt32(i.SubItems[4].Text) <= Convert.ToInt32(tenthousand.ToString()))
     {
         labelVideoViews2.Text = "GREAT";
         labelVideoViews2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
     }
  }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Serg That checks for column 1, Im checking for column 5. And even if I replace it, wont it still check the values of the last item only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like that?

```
getFirstItemInXColumn(4);
```

The number stands for the index of the subItem.

```
private void getFirstItemInXColumn(int subItemIndex)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (listView1.Items[i].SubItems[subItemID].ToString() != "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("First Item found at: X:"+subItemID.ToString()+"Y:"+i.ToString()+"is "+ listView1.Items[i].SubItems[subItemID].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

In my case I'm checking for the first item in the 4th subitemcolumn (5th column) which is not nothing.